# Resources for the "ah ha" moment when learning Bayes' theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes

I've been studying statistics for a little while and I keep coming back to Bayes' theorem trying to relearn it and have that "ah ha" moment with it. I keep coming back to it because I understand just how important Bayes is in statistics and I want to have a deep understanding of it aside from just applying the formula. So, are there any resources, series of problem, lectures, diagrams etc. that really popped the lid off Bayes for you and if so what were they? Thanks again for the input

Comment: Figure out whether the following statement is True or False:  For events $A$ and $B$, $$P(A\mid B) = P(B\mid A) \Rightarrow P(A) = P(B).$$

Comment: It would help if you could explain more about what kind of insight it is you feel you're presently lacking. I would say "keep applying it" is actually one part of coming to understand it, especially if you're having difficulty getting the point. I don't think there's anything mysterious; it's a basic (but very useful) result that follows from applying a definition of [conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_an_axiom_of_probability) two different ways. The fact that it lets you swap the conditioning about is central to reasoning about unknowns given data

Answer (score 3):

I think it's hard to beat Cohen's classic 1994 paper in the American Psychologist, "The earth is round, (p<.05)". You can always find it somewhere on Google, e.g. http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~maccoun/PP279_Cohen1.pdf.  He includes a brilliant example based on a medical screening test, and discusses the implications for interpreting p-values.